# Why does V2 decrease for intersection takeoff

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, performance-calculation, v-speeds

I have noticed that the VR and V2 decreases for same FLEX when departing from an intersection runway even when sufficient stop margin is available. What is the reason for this? And also does EFB calculate takeoff performance based on balanced field?

Comment: I suspect the issue is the climb gradient required for obstacle clearance assumptions.  the intersection takeoff moves my point of liftoff down the down the runway by some number of feet.  A full runway V2 may be based on me being off 3,000 feet before the departure end, which equates to a certain minimum climb gradient.  If I am lifting off with 1,500 feet remaining, I may need a steeper climb gradient to meet the same obstacle clearance expectations.  Similar to complying with an non-diverse runway ODP by making an earlier liftoff.

Comment: @Max Isn’t V2 typically lower than Vxse?  And thus you’d expect a higher V2 to clear a closer obstacle?

Comment: Could it have to do with the V1 policy your operator has adopted? Are you at Max FLEX in your scenario? EFB can unbalance for certain situations if your performance department has customised it accordingly, as far as I recall. In your case, it could be as simple as the EFB utilizing the whole runway to carry more energy even though minimum V2 is much lower, I guess.